# How can I get a new ApiAuthorizationDbContext in my Controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

The ApiAuthorizationDbContext is my default DBContext.
Now how do I get this context in a controller?
I can create the normal DBContext with new `DbContext()` but with the `ApiAuthorizationDbContext` I have to give options where I don't know how to get them.

My ApiAuthorizationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SiteSettings> SiteSettings { get; set; }


    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            AppSettings.DbOptions(optionsBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public class TenantHelper 
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public TenantHelper(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public static List<Tenant> GetAllTenants()
    {
        List<Tenant> tenants = new List<Tenant>();

        tenants = _context.Tenants.ToList();

        return tenants;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you explicitly want a separate DbContext for tracking purposes, or do you just want to use a DbContext in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependency injection in your application allows you to use any object as a set of functionalities that can be reused by multiple objects, to do add your database context as an dependency injection you should add it to the Startup.cs file that the .NetCore Web Applications default template creates.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
}
```

Now your context can be injected in any object constructor of your application and you can save it as a property to be accessed at any point of that object scope

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public MyController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    private void MethodA()
    {
      //accessing dbcontext
      _dbContext.MyTable.ToList();
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Apparently OP meant that he wants his `TenantHelper` to accessible on all his application, still is a problem that dependency injection solves but just a quick rework needs to be done.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //This adds your object as a reusable set of functions that is initialized for every different request
    services.AddScoped<TenantHelper>();
}
```

Now do the same process to inject your `TenantHelper` in your other code as you did on the `ApplicationDbContext`

Comment: That's exactly what I tried before, but then I get: "For the non-static field, the method or the property "TenantHelper._context" an object reference is required".

Comment: @n00dle are you trying to access your context from a static method or object?

Comment: No exactly as described above. It is a non-static class.

Comment: @n00dle add your source code to your question because the code above is compilable

Comment: I added it above

Comment: @n00dle like i said your method is static

Comment: But how can I use this function in another class? I have to initialize my helper and that with the DBContext I don't have

Comment: @n00dle you dont want it static, the same way you added your context as a reusable object like my aswner explains you can do to that helper, instead .AddDbContext() you use AddScoped()/AddTransient()/AddSingleton depending on how you want your container life cycle works

Answer (score -2):

Create library with you ApiAuthorizationDbContext and put reference from this lib in your project with controller

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question asks for a way to create an instance. OP already managed to reference the DbContext class, but doesn't know how to instantiate it.